# Is this graph a bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjX62.png)

This question has come up in a CS exam that I have to take, however my solution is different from the one given and I can't see why I'm incorrect. I'd love to know what someone else thinks!

Comment: what is your solution?

Comment: @cineel my solution is that the graph is bipartite. With two sets, A: V1, V2, V3 and B: V2, V4, V6

Comment: @DanWhite please revise your definition of bipartite graph. And revise your comment (V2 appears twice, V5 not at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a characterization of bipartite graphs: A graph is bipartite iff it does not contain an odd cycle.

In your graph, there is an odd cycle: $(v_2,v_4,v_5)$. So it's not bipartite.

Comment: Thank you! I see exactly where I made an error. And this is so obvious to me now- oops